# Concerns About Guidelines for Representing Nontransferable Relationships on an Entity Relationship Diagram

Tags: database-design, erd

I am currently enrolled in the online Oracle Academy Database Design Course, which briefly talks about the concept of nontransferable relationships. I understand the concept behind them, but the course's vague details left me with a few of questions.

1. Can nontransferable relationships exist between entities which are connected with a 1:1 or M:M relationship? All of the example provided by Oracle depicted 1:M relationships.
2. Can the diamond used to represent the nontransferable relationship be drawn on either end of the relationship, whether they are optional or mandatory? I believe they can only appear on the mandatory end of the relationship, but I want to be sure.
3. Similarly, can the diamond used to represent the nontransferable relationship potentially appear on BOTH ends of the relationship?

The following are a couple of examples provided by the Oracle Academy:

[image: Example1]
[image: Example2]